# Swift interpreter complaining about type casting

Tags: swift, casting

Why is the interpreter complaining about the following code?

```
let interestingNumbers:[String: Array<Int>] = [
    "Prime": [2, 3, 5, 7, 223, 13],
    "Fibonacci": [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8],
    "Square": [1, 4, 9, 16, 25],
]

let r: Array<Int> = interestingNumbers["Prime"]
```

> Value of optional type '[Int]?' must be unwrapped to a value of type
> '[Int]'

Comment: There is no Swift interpreter. The only implementations of Swift (that I know of) are the open source Apple implementation (which is compiled, via LLVM), and RemObjects Silver (which is cross-compiled to the CLR, JVM, WebAssembly or several other targets).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing `interestingNumbers["Prime"]` returns an **optional** value `[Int]?` and not `[Int]` as you declared.

This is because you don't know if a dictionary contains a key - it may be missing (then a returned value is *nil*). For that reason accessing a dictionary value returns an *optional* value.

You may force-unwrap it:

```
let r: [Int] = interestingNumbers["Prime"]!
```

or provide a default value:

```
let r: [Int] = interestingNumbers["Prime"] ?? [] // some default value if the key is missing
```

```
let r: [Int] = interestingNumbers["Prime", default: []] // some default value if the key is missing
```

or make `r` optional:

```
let r: [Int]? = interestingNumbers["Prime"]
```

Also, Swift can automatically infer the type of an expression, which means there is no need (*usually*) to specify the type explicitly:

```
let r: [Int] = interestingNumbers["Prime"]!
```

In the following:

```
let r = interestingNumbers["Prime"]!
```

`r` will automatically be of type `[Int]`.

In the same way in the following expression:

```
let r = interestingNumbers["Prime"]
```

`r` will be of type `[Int]?`.

*Note:* In Swift it's preferred to write `[Int]` instead of `Array<Int>`.

Comment: Thank you.That is where I do not unterstand. If I write let interestingNumbers:[String: Array<Int>] .. does not mean I am stating that it cannot return nil array but exactly an Array<Int>?

Comment: Now I got it, if the key does not exist it will return a nil. Thanks

Comment: Another way: `let r = interestingNumbers[“Prime”, default: [])`

Comment: Let Swift interpret the type of `r`.  Also, the preferred way to write `Array<Int>` is `[Int]`.

Comment: @vacawama Thanks, I updated my answer with your comments.

Comment: I'd leave the `??` example, because it is valid as well.  Since OP is new to Swift, also encourage them to let Swift infer the type of `r`.